# External log4j2 configuration file

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I have a spring web application using log4j2 as a logging system.
log4j2 : 2.6.2
slf4j : 1.7.21

i have got a log4j2.xml in my classpath used in production.

I want to use a different configuration file for development, especially when i run the server from Eclipse.

i tried to add -Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Dev\log4j2.xml to the Default VM arguments in eclipse as well as the server parameters but no luck so far, it's always picking up the log4j2.xml from the classpath

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try prepending the file with the `file:` prefix. `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///C:/Dev/log4j2.xml`

If you're using a spring properties file you can also do:

```
logging.config = file:///C:/Dev/log4j2.xml
```

Comment: no luck, i went to the Run Configurations, Tomcat > Arguments and the VM arguments text box. I added " -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:C:\Dev\log4j2.xml it's still picking up the log4j2.xml from the classpath

Comment: I fixed the path a little. But I doubt that would make a difference. You can verify that the property is reaching your application by checking System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile").

Comment: i have tried different ways but it always picks the file in WEB-INF/

Answer (score 1):

I tried below approach and it works for me;

String fullyQualifiedFilePath = "/mnt/test/log4j2local.properties";
Configurator.initialize(null,fullyQualifiedFilePath );

Comment: This is also works for me to load the external xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can do the things in two ways.

1. Application.properties
2. VM Arguments under Run-Configurations.

Case 1 : Application-properties

(Mac OS)
logging.config=file:/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/log4j2.xml

(Windows OS)
logging.config=file:/XXX/XXX/XXX/log4j2.xml

Case 2: Project Run-Configurations

-Dlogging.config=/Users/XXX/XXXX/log4j2.xml

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Why is your Mac version rooted at 'Users' and why does your windows version use a Linux-style path?

Comment: It's just for reference only. Its the absolute path of the file in your system. Thats all. For Windows, usually it starts with C:/ or D:/ etc.,

Answer (score 0):

We have requirement to config the external log file, if not exist then use default config file in WEB-INF.

Here is the code in our projects, which i used the load external configuration log file if exist, if not load default in WEB-INF:

```
public class Log4jLoader extends Log4jServletContextListener {

  private String LOG_FROM_CLASSPATH = "WEB-INF/log4j2.xml";

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    File f = new File(getLog4jPath());
    String path = f.exists() ? f.getAbsolutePath() : getFilefromClassPath(event);
    Configurator.initialize(null, path);
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoader.class)
        .info("load log4j2 from: {}", path);
  }
  private String getLog4jPath(){
       return "logFilePath";
  }
}
```